# Communication(IPC) between c++ XPCOM component and COM service

Tags: c++, visual-c++, service, ipc, xpcom

Can Anyone guide me regarding IPC between c++ XPCOM component and COM service.

any help is greatly accepted.....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there's no support either in XPCOM or COM to communicate with each other. Sorry.

Comment: I am still trying to communicate between XPCOM and COM service.

Comment: uptil i am able to communicate from xpcom to COM service. but from COM service to XPCOM still problem...do you know any another way how to do IPC from XPCOM to another process?